# Policy to audit resource group that contains resources

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I am looking to configure policy to audit resource groups that contains resources, whether have the particular tag name or not. Policy should not audit the empty resource groups. My requirement is only to perform audit for tags, if the resource group contains resources. Is it a possible scenario for creating policy?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, Azure Policy makes it possible to audit, and even enforce tagging rules and conventions on your resources.

The [Audit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/effects#audit) effect can be used in your policy to create a warning event in the activity log when evaluating a non-compliant resource, but it doesn't stop the request.

Such a policy rule can look similar to the following:

```
"policyRule": {
  "if": {
    "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
    "exists": "false"
  },
  "then": {
    "effect": "audit"
  }
}
```

Here are some more examples that demonstrate [assigning policies for tag compliance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/tag-policies).

**Note:** To see if your Azure resource supports tagging, see [Tag support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/tag-support).